# Weird type signature while combining IO actions

Tags: haskell, types, io, monads

On my my machine the following code prints:

```
 $ ghc --version
 The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
 $ runhaskell Why.hs
[1,1,1]
[2,2,2]
```

But on FP Complete it produces an error: (Unless I switch to `GHC 7.8 Preview`, LPaste for cloning http://lpaste.net/108096)

```
src/Main.hs@4:7-4:13No instance for (Monad ((->) (IO Int)))
  arising from a use of `return'   
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Monad ((->) (IO Int)))
In the expression: return 3
In an equation for `num': num = return 3
```

Here's the code. I was trying to make a function that repeats an IO action times an IO Int action.
I noticed that GHC derived a weird type signature for `num`.

```
import Control.Monad

-- Notice the weird type signature, for - it seems - no reason
num :: IO Int -> Int
num = return 3

rep :: IO Int -> IO [Int]
rep = num >>= replicateM

rep' :: IO Int -> IO [Int]
rep' = do x <- num
      replicateM x

main :: IO ()
main = do print =<< rep (return 1)
          print =<< rep' (return 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return 3 :: IO Int -> Int` has nothing whatsoever to do with IO. In fact, you could have written

```
num :: a -> Int
num = return 3
```

same thing. `return` uses the `(a -> )` monad here, whose definition is `return = const`. So effectively you've written

```
num _ = 3
```

and the `IO` action is just thrown away.

Now as to why it doesn't work on FP complete: the `Monad (a -> )` instance has only been included in the Prelude since GHC-7.6:

> GHCi, version 7.6.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
>   Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package base ... linking ... done.
>   Prelude> :i Monad
>   class Monad m where
>     (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
>     (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
>     return :: a -> m a
>     fail :: String -> m a
>       -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
>   instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
>   instance Monad (Either e) -- Defined in `Data.Either'
>   instance Monad [] -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
>   instance Monad IO -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
>   **instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'**
>   Prelude>

whereas

> GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
>   Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package base ... linking ... :done.
>   Prelude> :i Monad
>   class Monad m where
>     (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
>     (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
>     return :: a -> m a
>     fail :: String -> m a
>       -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
>   instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
>   instance Monad [] -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
>   instance Monad IO -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
>   Prelude>

To get this instance in older versions, you need to `import Control.Monad.Instances`.

Which is I think *not* what you're actually looking for. I don't know what you mean by "repeats an IO action times an IO Int action", but I reckon it's something like

```
IO a -> IO Int -> IO [a]
```

If that's it then *start with this signature*. Don't let GHC deduce top-level types, this circumvents the bug-protection the type system gives you.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add how did you find out that `return` is using the `(a ->)` monad? When I asked GHC it derived the type of `num`, it returned `:: IO Int -> Int` so I thought I was sure I was using the right instance of monad.

Comment: What I wanted was `(read <$> getLine >>=) . flip replicateM` to the signature of `rep` was correct. I just wasn't sure about signature of `num`

Comment: GHC most certainly did not deduce `IO Int -> Int` as the type of `return 3`. What exactly did you ask it?

Comment: It did. `num` didn't had a type signature. I loaded Why.hs into Ghci and asked for type of num using `:t num`. It returned `num :: IO Int -> Int`

Comment: Oh, I see. [The dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) strikes again... GHC knows that `return 3` should be polymorphic in the monad, but because it's top-level it doesn't want a polymorphic type, so it infers _some rubbish_. This is never useful. Switch off by using `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}`, and/or write the top-level signatures yourself instead of asking GHC. Indeed, it's generally a good idea to write your programs "outside in", i.e. start with definitions like `foo :: a -> (b->c) -> q`; `foo = undefined`.